# Очистка текста от html - кода

Tags: python

В javascript на сайте содержится некоторый Json, который я вытащил с помошью регулярки.

Но в Json содержатся html - элементы. Можно ли как нибудь от них избавиться, оставив только текст?

Например

```
<div>Гарантированный анализ:</b> протеин 0,0014%, жиры 0,00029%, зола 5,3%, влага 81%, кальций 5,2%, калий 0,026%, магний 0,000014%, натрий 0,000047%, фосфор 0,0011%.</div><div style="text-align: justify;"><b>Состав: </b>минералы, сахар, молоко и молочные продукты, концентрат черной смородины.</div><div style="text-align: justify;">  </div><div style="text-align: justify;"><b>Гарантированный анализ:</b> протеин 0,0014%, жиры 0,00029%, зола 5,3%, влага 81%, кальций 5,2%, калий 0,026%, магний 0,000014%, натрий 0,000047%, фосфор 0,0011%.</div><div style="text-align: justify;">  </div><div style="text-align: justify;"><b>Добавки на 1 л:</b> витамин С 200 мг.</div>
```

**Update:** на этом не срабатывает данные способы:

```
\r\n\u003cul>\r\n  \u003cli style=\"text-align: justify;\">Полноценный корм в виде хлопьев с натуральными усилителями цвета\u003c/li>
```

**Update**
Если вывести bs4 в консоль, то выводит

```
Результат: 
Полноценный корм в виде хлопьев с натуральными усилителями цвета
Поддерживает яркость и полноту окраса всех видов красных, оранжевых и желтых декоративных рыб 
Эффект усиления цвета виден всего через две недели 
БиоАктив-формула поддерживает здоровой иммунную систему 
Содержит пребиотики для лучшего переваривания пищи 
Для здорового роста рыб и чистой воды
```

Все хорошо, но если я занесу значение в словарь, и потом этот словарь выведу, то у меня проскакивают спец - символы

```
{'composition': 'Ингредиенты:\xa0рыба и побочные рыбные продукты, зерновые культуры, дрожжи, моллюски и раки, экстракты растительного белка, масла и жиры, водоросли, сахар (олигофруктоза 0,9%), минеральные вещества.\n\n\n\nАналитический состав:\n\n\
```

Comment: ну если нужна обычная non-safe чистка, то можно и регуляркой. `re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', text)` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python

Comment: @strawdog спасибо за ссылку, сейчас попробую bs4 почистить

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Удалить тэги можно несколькими способами:

**С использованием регулярного выражения**

```py
import re

regexp = re.compile('<.*?>')
cleaned_string = re.sub(regexp, '', html_string)
```

**С помощью BeautifulSoup**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
cleaned_string = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "lxml").text
```

**С помощью ElementTree**

```py
cleaned_string = ''.join(xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(html_string).itertext())
```

Comment: на этом не срабатывает 
\r\n\u003cul>\r\n  \u003cli style=\"text-align: justify;\">Полноценный корм в виде хлопьев с натуральными усилителями цвета\u003c/li>

Comment: @danilshik на этом и не должен, здесь нет никакого валидного html кода

Comment: @andreymal я думаю это <ul><li style="text-align: justify;">Полноценный корм в виде хлопьев с натуральными усилителями цвета</li> .Думаю это проблема кодировки, но как исправить не знаю

Comment: @danilshik ну к вопросу чистки html кода это уже не имеет отношения